# How vue3 keeps tables synced and unaffected by pagination

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

[界面如下](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncKs0.png)

I inserted the totals data into the first position of the array to get the list, but the totals row didn't now be in the first row of the page when pagination
For example, my pagination condition is to display 3 rows per page, but I need to add a total number to these 3 lines, which will cause my pagination to fail, because the page display shows 3 lists that override the total number
I'd like to ask if there is any other solution that can put the total number of rooms on the first item of the table and implement it in a vue3 way
Here's a vue3 code:

```
  <a-table class="table-container"
               row-key="id"
               :loading="loading"
               :pagination="state.pagination"
               :columns="state.columns"
               :data="state.tableList"
               :bordered="true"
               :stripe="true"
               :size="'medium'"
               @page-change="onPageChange" >
  </a-table>
```

Comment: Vue cannot do anything, it depends on the library you use

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The library does not provide an api to  fulfill your needs,but I implement it using nested columns ,[Hope it helps.](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Hello Is there a specific way to implement it, I would like to refer to it

Comment: Just check the links  I provided above